# Tcpdump for capturing and calculating checksum of binary HTTP response body

Tags: linux, http, networking, tcpdump

I'm seeing some corrupted images in a cache service, and I'm suspecting the upstream image source not the cache service itself.

In order to tell whether the corruption happens during loading the image into the cache or before, it would be nice to capture all incoming HTTP packets with content type "image/something" and calculate a checksum of the response body. Anyone know how to do that? Doesn't have to be tcpdump if there's any other program more suited.

Comment: Note that the body may be traveling with chunks, so a checksum would need to remove the chunk headers. You could also encouter range queries (but let's assume you do not have range queries playing around). Capture everything with tcpdump and load the result in wireshark, you'll certainly find the extracted binary content from there.

Comment: The Content-length header is set to the correct number of bytes, so from a HTTP perspective it's not chunked

Comment: You can have chunks even with a Content-Length header, and `Transfer-Encoding : chunked` has the priority, message is still valid (unless the Content-Length information is false, then it's invalid)